# PLSQL Trigger - Update another table before inserting a new record

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have 3 tables that are related to each other:

- `ACCOUNTS`
- `CARDS`
- `TRANSACTIONS`

I want to change the money amount from account every time I execute a new transaction. I want to decrease the account value with each new move.

I tried writing this trigger:

```
create or replace trigger ceva_trig1
before insert on miscari
for each row
declare
  new_val micari.valoare%tipe := new.valoare;
begin
  update conturi
  set    sold = sold - new_val
  where  nrcont = (select nrcont
                   from   conturi
                          join carti_de_credit on conturi.nrcont = carti_de_credit.nrcont
                          join miscari on carti_de_credit.nr_card = miscari.nrcard)
  and sold >= new_val; 
end;
```

May anyone help me correct the syntax that crashes here?

Comment: Please edit your question to add in the error message that you get.

Comment: although `%tipe` should be `%type`

Answer (score 3):

I've created those tables with minimal number of columns, just to make trigger compile.

```
SQL> create table conturi
  2    (sold   number,
  3     nrcont number
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> create table miscari
  2    (valoare number,
  3     nrcard  number
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> create table carti_de_credit
  2    (nrcont  number,
  3     nr_card number
  4    );

Table created.
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger ceva_trig1
  2    before insert on miscari
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    update conturi c
  6    set    c.sold = c.sold - :new.valoare
  7    where  c.nrcont = (select r.nrcont
  8                         from carti_de_credit r
  9                         where r.nrcont = c.nrcont
 10                           and r.nr_card = :new.nrcard
 11                      )
 12      and c.sold >= :new.valoare;
 13  end;
 14  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

---

How does it differ from your code? Like this:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger ceva_trig1
  2  before insert on miscari
  3  for each row
  4  declare
  5    new_val micari.valoare%tipe := new.valoare;
  6  begin
  7    update conturi
  8    set    sold = sold - new_val
  9    where  nrcont = (select nrcont
 10                     from   conturi
 11                            join carti_de_credit on conturi.nrcont = carti_de_credit.nrcont
 12                            join miscari on carti_de_credit.nr_card = miscari.nrcard)
 13    and sold >= new_val;
 14  end;
 15  /

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for TRIGGER CEVA_TRIG1:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/11     PL/SQL: Item ignored
2/26     PLS-00208: identifier 'TIPE' is not a legal cursor attribute
4/3      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
10/15    PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "NEW_VAL": invalid identifier
10/15    PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed

SQL>
```

Explained:

- it isn't `tipe` but `type`
- new column values are referenced with a colon, i.e. `:new.valoare`
- you shouldn't make typos regarding table & column names; it is `miscari`, not `micari`
- it is bad practice to write query which references the same table (`miscari`, line #12) trigger is created for. As it is being changed, you can't select values from it as it is *mutating*

  - lucky you, you don't have to do that at all. How? Have a look at my code.

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to maintain an ongoing for transactions in one table in another table is always a bad idea. Admittedly in an extremely few cases it's necessary, but should be the design of last resort not an initial one; even when necessary it's still a bad idea and therefore requires much more processing and complexity.  
In this instance after you correct all the errors @Littlefoot points out then your real problems begin. What do you do when: (Using Littlefoot's table definitions)

- I delete a row from miscari?
- I update a row in miscari?
- The subselect for nrcont returns 0 rows?
- The condition sold >= new_val is False?

If any of conditions occur the value for sold in conturi is incorrect and may not be correctable from values in the source table - miscari. An that list may be just the beginning of the issues you face.

Suggestion: Abandon the idea of keeping an running account of transaction values. Instead derive it when needed. You can create a view that does that and select from the view.  
 So maybe instead of "create table conturi ..."